# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider' to Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.MembershipDataProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, sitefinity-8

I am new to sitefinity and MVC, I have the following code:-

```
MembershipDataProvider membership;

if (HttpContext.Request != null && HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null &&
    HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Authority != null &&
    HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Authority.Equals(businessprovider.GetValueByKey(SitefinityURI)))
{
  **membership = Membership.Providers[Constants.CredentialServiceMembershipProvider];**

}
```

I am using Sitefinity membership Provider and trying to get a collection of membership provider for sitefinity  but I am getting the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider' to Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.MembershipDataProvider.

Comment: If you want to get one instance of `MembershipProvider` from `Membership.Providers` collection, then you should change `MembershipDataProvider membership;` to `MembershipProvider membership;`

Comment: i want to use sitefinity Membership Provider (MembershipDataProvider) instead of  ASP.net provider(MembershipProvider)